# Rank letter counts in pyspark into RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to spark, and was trying to count the frequency of each letter in a list of names and then rank the top 10 letters. I am having trouble at the end when building the tuple, can anyone please help?

```
rdd_1 = sc.parallelize(['Scott', 'Steven', 'Sara', 'Mike', 'Mary', 'Joe', 'Jake'])

letters = rdd_1.flatMap (lambda x: list(x.lower()))

letters.collect()
```

output for letter is:

['s',
'c',
'o',
't',
't',
's',
't',
'e',
'v',
'e',
'n',
's',
'a',
'r',
'a',
'm',
'i',
'k',
'e',
'm',
'a',
'r',
'y',
'j',
'o',
'e',
'j',
'a',
'k',
'e']

```
instances1 = letters.map (lambda letr: (letr, 1))
aggCounts1 = instances1.reduceByKey (lambda x, y: x + y)
aggCounts1.collect()
```

output for aggCounts1.collect() is:

[('s', 3),
('r', 2),
('i', 1),
('y', 1),
('e', 5),
('a', 4),
('m', 2),
('j', 2),
('t', 3),
('n', 1),
('k', 2),
('c', 1),
('o', 2),
('v', 1)]

I want to find the top 10 words and then rank them

```
topWords = aggCounts1.top (10, lambda x : x[1])
topWords[:3]
```

top 3 words:
[('e', 5),
('a', 4),
('s', 3)]

```
topTen = sc.parallelize(range(10))
```

This is what I made for the tuple result:

```
# this is incorrect syntax
result = topTen.map (lambda ltrs,nums: ltrs for ltrs in topWords and nums in topTen (topWords[0], topTen) )
```

I am trying to get something like this:

[('e', 0),
('a', 1),
('s', 2),
('t', 3),
('r', 4),
('m', 5),
('j', 6),
('k', 7),
('o', 8),
('i', 9)]

Comment: Answer clear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zipWithIndex` as last step and then `map` accordingly.

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex.html.

Narrow transformation here.

UPDATE

In the right way as you have a list.

Full code:

```
%python

rdd_1 = sc.parallelize(['Scott', 'Steven', 'Sara', 'Mike', 'Mary', 'Joe', 'Jake']) 
letters = rdd_1.flatMap (lambda x: list(x.lower())) letters.collect()

instances1 = letters.map (lambda letr: (letr, 1)) 
aggCounts1 = instances1.reduceByKey (lambda x, y: x + y) 

topWords2 = aggCounts1.sortBy(lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])).zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[1])) 
topWords2.take(20)
```